# NextPlease Firefox extension doesn't work in 3.6+. Any updates or similar extension?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, compatibility

I use a Firefox extension called NextPlease which allows me to use the keyboard to go to the next or previous page on web pages which have Previous/Next paging links. Like the Google search results. I downloaded a version from http://cisengineer.com/firefox/ for my Windows XP. On a Windows 7 FF 3.6 machine, Firefox can't import the extension because it's not compatible with FF 3.6 even though it worked in FF 3.6 in Windows XP.

Is there an update to this extension or is there a similar extension?
I downgraded to FF 3.5.7 to have the extension working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://board.mozest.com/viewthread.php?tid=33400&page=1

looks the Chinese got power browsing features sorted out..

now back to power browsing.. to any noobs start using mouse gestures check firegestures, some uber person posted some scripts to combo gestures+nextplease :P next = mouse >< , previous mouse <>

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time when Firefox updates, the only thing that makes an extension 'not compatible' is the fact that it's compatibility is set for the last version, unless very specific changes have been made to Firefox to break the current extension.

To get around this check, you can follow the following steps:

1. Open Firefox and type this into the address bar: `about:config`
2. Right click on the screen and select: `New -> Boolean`
3. For the name, type: `extensions.checkCompatibility.3.6`
4. For the value, select: `false`

This disables the check the Firefox performs when it disables 'non compatible' extensions. There is no guarantee that this will work, but it works in almost every case I've seen.

Be sure to check for updates of your extension as time goes on so that you can turn this feature back on once you get an update.

Comment: Thanks but the extension didn't work and the extension hasn't been updated since 2007.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to install [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6543) and be done with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version compatible with 3.6 on AMO now.